# Simple Eclipse Code Templates - Issue

Tags: eclipse, templates, configuration, settings, code-complete

Hi I have Code Templates enabled in Eclipse.

I just installed Eclipse for Java and Enabled Code Templates (From Code Assist Settings). I typed "sysout" Ctrl+Space, but I do not System.out.println.

Also, what exactly does Automatically Insert mean in the Code Completion options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Content assist can insert 'single' proposals automatically (you have to enable the corresponding preference for this on Java > Editor > Content Assist page).

P.S.  "sysout" works for me.